# Google GSutil create folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket, gsutil, cl

How can u create a new folder inside a bucket in google cloud storage using the gsutil command?

I tried using the same command in creating bucket but still got an error

```
gsutil mb -l us-east1 gs://my-awesome-bucket/new_folder/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

The concept of directory is abstract in Google Cloud Storage.

Back until 2021, the docs ([How Subdirectories Work](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506223006/https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork)) stated:

> gsutil provides the illusion of a hierarchical file tree atop the "flat" name space supported by the Google Cloud Storage service. To the service, the object gs://your-bucket/abc/def.txt is just an object that happens to have "/" characters in its name. There is no "abc" directory; just a single object with the given name.

The current docs ([Simulated folders](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects#simulated-folders)) clarifies that today, some tools, like Google Cloud Console, are capable of showing folders:

> In order to help you organize objects in your Cloud Storage buckets, some tools simulate folders, and both the JSON and XML APIs have capabilities that let you design your own naming scheme to simulate folders.
> [...]
>
> The Google Cloud console creates a visual representation of folders that resembles a local file browser.

So you cannot "create" a directory like in a traditional File System with `gsutil`, these are just "simulated" by tools like the console:

> If you create an empty folder using the Google Cloud console, Cloud Storage creates a zero-byte object as a placeholder. [...] This placeholder is discoverable by other tools when listing the objects in the bucket, for example when using the list method in the JSON API.

Comment: But apparently, they allow to do it from the console. Which made it confusing for me. :/

Comment: @akki my answer was more than 5 years old, so I've updated it to match today's documentation. Basically, the concept of "creating" directories still doesn't exist, but Google have now simulated this concept (with the console for example) to help people organize their objects. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your commitment to keep the answer up-to-date even after so many years.

Answer (score 21):

If you're clear about what folders and objects already exist in the bucket, then you can create a new 'folder' with gsutil by copying an object into the folder.

```
>mkdir test
>touch test/file1
>gsutil cp -r test gs://my-bucket
Copying file://test\file1 [Content- 
Type=application/octet-stream]...
/ [1 files][    0.0 B/    0.0 B]
Operation completed over 1 objects.

>gsutil ls gs://my-bucket
gs://my-bucket/test/

>gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/test
gs://my-bucket/test/file1
```

It won't work if the local directory is empty.

More simply:

```
>touch file2
>gsutil cp file2 gs://my-bucket/new-folder/
Copying file://test\file2 [Content- ...

>gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/new-folder
gs://my-bucket/new-folder/file2
```

Be aware of the potential for [Surprising Destination Subdirectory Naming](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork#potential-for-surprising-destination-subdirectory-naming). E.g. if the target directory already exists as an object. For an automated process, a more robust approach would be to use [rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync).

I don't know if its possible to create an empty folder with gsutil. For that, use the console's *Create Folder* button.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create folders with gsutil as gsutil does not support it (workaround see below).

However, it is supported via:

- UI in browser
- write your own GCS client (we have written our own custom client which can create folders)

So even if Google has a flat name space structure as the other answer correctly points out, it still has the possibility to create single folders as individual objects. Unfortunately gsutil does not expose this.

*(Ugly) workaround with gsutil*: Add a dummy file into a folder and upload this dummy file - but the folder will be gone once you delete this file, unless other files in that folder are present.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from Google cloud help:

Copy the object to a folder in the bucket
Use the gsutil cp command to create a folder and copy the image into it:

gsutil cp gs://my-awesome-bucket/kitten.png gs://my-awesome-bucket/just-a-folder/kitten3.png

This works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a folder with **gsutil** on **GCS**.

But you can copy an existing folder with **gsutil** to **GCS**.

To copy an existing folder with **gsutil** to **GCS**, **a folder must not be empty** and **the flag "-r"** is needed as shown below otherwise you will get error if a folder is empty or you forgot **the flag -r**:

```
gsutil cp -r <non-empty-folder> gs://your-bucket
      // "-r" is needed for folder
```

You cannot create an empty folder with mb